# Scripts called from another script don't work correctly when run through task scheduler in Powershell 5.0

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have stripped the script down so it basically does nothing but it still has open-with errors. I removed the two scripts it was calling.  I believe that I am now calling them correctly but I still have a problem with this stripped down version. I am starting it with this command which works for my other scripts:

Powershell.exe and the argument is "-command C:\powershell\scripts\production\GetServerObjects.ps1 @Echo %errorlevel%"

This is my first post and I am getting warnings that I'm not doing it right.  I'll work on that!

Example of the zombie processes as seen through process monitor is here:[open- with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs0GM.jpg)

Script is below.  It either has some errors where the server does not know how to open something or I am starting it wrong through the task scheduler.

```
#  Get_Server_Objects.ps1
#  Add snapins, modules, dot source needed scripts

. "C:\Powershell\Scripts\Production\invoke-Sqlcmd2.ps1"

if  (-Not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name SQLSERVER))
        {
            Import-Module SQLServer
        }  

$ResultsDir ="C:\Powershell\Results"
$DateSuffix = "{0:MMdd}" -f (Get-Date)
$DaysToKeep = 1      #days of results to keep.  This keeps 2 days worth.

# Create a Scripter object and set the required scripting options. 
$scrp = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($srv)
$scrp.Options.ExtendedProperties = $True

# Make sure server list is available before proceeding.

try
{
    $Serverlist = get-content "C:\Powershell\Scripts\Production\serversshort.txt" -ea stop
}
catch
{
    $output = $_.ErrorDetails
    throw $output
    Exit 1
}

#  Main Processing Loop
foreach ($Instance in $ServerList) 
{
    $InstDir  = $Instance.replace('\','_')
    if (!(Test-Path "$ResultsDir\$InstDir\"))                            
         {New-Item  "$ResultsDir\$InstDir\" -Type directory}

# create new file names.  Automatically writes over any file of the same name.

        $LoginFile = "$Instdir"+'_'+"$dateSuffix" + '_CreateLogins.txt'
        $DBFile = "$Instdir"+'_'+"$dateSuffix" + '_CreateDBs.txt'
        $JobFile = "$Instdir" +'_' +"$dateSuffix" + '_Createjobs.txt'
        $ConfigFile = "$Instdir" +'_' +"$dateSuffix" + '_config.txt'
        $LinkFile = "$Instdir" +'_' +"$dateSuffix" + '_LinkedServers.txt'
        $DiskFile = "$Instdir" +'_' +"$dateSuffix" + '_DiskLayout.txt'
        $CompFile = "$Instdir" +'_' +"$dateSuffix" + '_CompLevels.txt'
```

}

Comment: you are normally required to specify the powershell executable in the `program/script` box & then the arguments in the `add arguments` box. putting ALL of that in the `program/script` box is known to be problematic.

Comment: I am starting the primary script as you say.  The problem comes in with the two scripts that the primary script runs.  When I run process monitor or task monitor, I see open-with instances which are kind of zombie processes that use up memory.  It tells me that the two scripts run from the primary script don't know they should be running as Powershell scripts.  .

Comment: arg! i  misread your post. [*blush*] there are other ways to start a new instance of PoSh from inside a current PoSh session. the call `&` operator and `Start-Process` come to mind.

Comment: I'll give that a try and let you know!  I did read about Start-Process but didn't understand the & symbol,

Comment: for the call operator, take a look at >>> Call operator - Run - PowerShell - SS64.com — https://ss64.com/ps/call.html <<<

Comment: Thank  you.  I had found that very good reference on my own.  I started the scripts with this  statement: & Powershell.exe "C:\Powershell\Scripts\Production\GetTest.ps1 Env:localhost"  but this morning the server was flooded with zombies.  I did not use the Start-Process because I thought that just calling the statement with the & operator was equivalent to what I was doing before - just kicking off the job.  Script takes a long time to run but I will test it with an abbreviated list of servers to see if I can find the problem.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to know you got it working ... [*grin*]

Comment: Sorry - I sent that last comment off before it was complete.  Not working.  No grins here.

Comment: you will need to update your Original Post with a simplified version of the code you are dealing with. just enuf to show the problem, no more than that.

Answer (score 0):

To review - Script that ran two other scripts produced zombie processes when run through task scheduler after update to Powershell 5.0.

I had to make two changes:

1. Previously I just kicked off the internal script by using name of the script.  I thought that powershell.exe script.ps1 would work but it didn't.  Thanks to Lee Dailey for suggesting this format which starts a new instance of Powershell.

   & start-process "C:\Powershell\Scripts\Production\Script.ps1"
2. After making the above change, I was still seeing zombie processes.  After deleting virtually all the lines from the script, I still had the problem.  My usual method of setting up the job by having it run Powershell with the argument of
   "-command C:\powershell\scripts\production\Script.ps1 @Echo %errorlevel%"
   did not work.  I finally got it to work by using the browse button to select the script.  In the argument box I just put  "@Echo %errorlevel%".  I assume this works because the default behavior of opening a .ps1 file in Powershell 5.0 is to run it with Powershell.  Still don't know why this script would not run with the Powershell + Arg technique but it is running now.